# Modal Not Closing on router replace in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, vue-router

[The screen gets unclickable on replacing the route using vue router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7rH4.png)

Below is the code of the change of route on successful signin

```
fb.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(function(result) {
      // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
      // var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      // console.log(token);
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user;

      var databaseReference = fb.database().ref();
      if (fb.auth().currentUser != null) {
        databaseReference.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
          if (
            snapshot
              .child("Doctors")
              .child(user.uid)
              .exists()
          ) {
            alert("The User is already registered as a doctor");
            fb.auth().signOut();
            window.$("#login").modal("hide");
            window.$("#signin").hide();
            router.go("/");
          } else {
            window.$("#login").modal("hide");
            var dataRef = fb
              .database()
              .ref("Users")
              .child(user.uid);
            var updates = {
              uid: user.uid,
              name: user.displayName,
              email: user.email
            };
            dataRef.update(updates);
            //window.$("#signin").hide();
            router.replace("HomePage");
          }
        });
      }
    })
```

As you can see that i have tried to hide model but the screen is still unclickable.I have tried all possible ways to the best of my knowledge.

Below is the code of Login.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="login">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="login"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="loginTitle"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-fill nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item" id="google">
                <a
                  class="nav-link active"
                  id="pills-home-tab"
                  data-toggle="pill"
                  href="#pills-login"
                  role="tab"
                  aria-controls="pills-login"
                  aria-selected="true"
                >
                  <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item" id="facebook">
                <a
                  class="nav-link"
                  id="pills-register-tab"
                  data-toggle="pill"
                  href="#pills-register"
                  role="tab"
                  aria-controls="pills-register"
                  aria-selected="false"
                >
                  <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="phone">
                <h3 class="text-center">Login With Phone</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone Number</label>
                  <input
                    type="tel"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="inputPhone"
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Enter Phone No"
                  />
                  <small
                    class="form-text text-muted"
                  >We'll never share your phone no with anyone else.</small>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="code">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Code</label>
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  v-model="email"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="inputCode"
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                  placeholder="Enter Login Code"
                />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="Login">LOGIN</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Below is the code of HomePage.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <nav id="navibar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Medico</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              id="navbarDropdown"
              role="button"
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >Account</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <button class="dropdown-item" id="signout">Logout</button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input
            class="form-control mr-sm-2"
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search"
          />
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <h1>This Is Home Page</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you add your template code?

Comment: And are you sure you want the popup? I think you might want signInWithRedirect

Comment: @JuanPabloUgas i have added the code please look into it

Comment: @JuanPabloUgas i want to hide the model when the login is successful and i want to redirect to HomePage from login page when the sign in is successful but actually the page is redirecting but the page to which it is redirected(HomePage) is become unclickable